# Этимология слова "радуга"

Tags: этимология

Задумалась о происхождении слова "радуга". "Дуга" — это понятно, а вот что означает часть слова "ра"?
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Информация из Интернета

Общеславянское – radoga.Этимология слова не ясна, существует несколько теорий, объясняющих его происхождение. В соответствии с одной из них, radoga является производным от праславянского корня radъ, значение которого аналогично англосаксонскому rot (радостный, благородный). Согласно другой этимологической гипотезе, корень rad является производным от Arda (имя одного из славянских вождей).

В ряде диалектов современного русского языка слово произносится как «райдуга», так же оно звучало в русском языке в XVII–XVIII вв. Некоторые исследователи языка склонны предполагать, что слово «райдуга», от которого произошло современное «радуга», имеет народную этимологию, образовалось в результате слияния слов «рай» и «дуга».
Родственным являются: Украинское – райдуга.

Comment: >Родственным являются: Украинское – райдуга.
Ещё одно название радуги на Украине - *веселка*. Слова *весел* и *рад* похожи по смыслу. Возможно, это аргумент в пользу описаной выше **Софией** версии, что
>radoga является производным от праславянского корня radъ

Comment: Вообще-то, ни разу не слышала слово "райдуга". Только "веселка", даже издательство детской литературы в Киеве такое есть.

Comment: Шанский говорит, что это украинский диалект.

Comment: >Вообще-то, ни разу не слышала слово "райдуга". Только "веселка", даже издательство детской литературы в Киеве такое есть.

Да, я тоже сразу про слово "веселка" вспомнил. И про издательство. :-)
Но "райдуга" я тоже встречал.

Comment: По ссылке страница с картинкой из укр. Википедии [Райдуга над Троещиною][1].

Троещина -- это район в Киеве на левом берегу Днепра.


  [1]: http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4_%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%94%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8E.jpg

Comment: Веселка - это что-то книжное, придуманное. В просторечии на Украине говорят именно "райдуга".

Comment: Ра - это славянский Бог Солнца, радуга - это дуга Бога Солнца, небесная дуга.

Comment: Ра? Славянский?  А не египетский ли?

Answer (score 1):

У Фасмера в статье "Радуга" говорится, что наиболее вероятно происхождение от radoga (производное от radъ - радость, радеть, ради и т.д.). Кстати, у Черныха "рад" - состояние особой приподнятости, испытываемой кем-то и связанной с оживлением (весёлостью) и расположением к кому-нибудь (ср. со значением "радеть").
[ссылка на Фасмера](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vasmer.php?id=431&vol=3)

К тому же [вот тут](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/novoe.php?id=190&vol=) подтверждается эта гипотеза названиями радуги в других вост.-слав. диалектах (*радавіца, радусник*).

Comment: И ещё. Хинди - ind-rad-hanush, а вот для сравнения в сербском - дуга.

Comment: Нет, явно в хинди не "рад", а иное - indradhanush (вот что тут, кто знает: "рад" или "Индра"?), а вот для сравнения в сербском - дуга. В языке маратхи - Indradhanuṣya, на санскрите - indracāpaḥ (вот так и хочется "Индру" увидеть, отчего народная этимология с "Ра-дугой" кажется имеющей место быть)...

Answer (score 0):

Если уж речь об Индии, то в санскрите
"rAdha" - дар, благосклонность
"rAdhas" - подарок, великодушие, богатство, щедрость, доброта, успех
"ga" - движение, путь
т.е. изначальное значение "путь радости", "дугой" она стала позже, по образцу понятного слова.